# Integration of piecewise defined function: $ f(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I think I am confusing myself too much on this.

Let $ f(x)=0$ for $x<1$, and $f(x)=1$ for $x\geq1$. What is $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$?

I am worried because $f$ is discontinuous at $1$. Does that make the answer different from zero, or make the function not integrable in that interval?

For example, $\int_0^2f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$+$\int_1^2f(x)\,dx$. For the second interval $f$ is constant at 1, so it can be taken outside the integral sign, but, that does not really apply for the first interval $0\leq x\leq1$, does it?

Comment: You can change the value of a function at a finite number of points and not change the Riemann integral. The proof, from the definition of Riemann integral, is not hard.

Comment: A related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586593/existence-of-the-integral?rq=1

Comment: Please try to choose more descriptive titles for your questions.

Comment: Agreed. I definitely lack creativity in this sector.  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(x)=\int f(x) \:\mathrm{d}x=
\begin{cases}
\int 1 \:\mathrm{d}x & x\geq1\\
\int 0 \:\mathrm{d}x & x<1
\end{cases}
$$
$$\therefore\:F(x)=\begin{cases}
x+C_1 & x\geq1\\
0+C_2 & x<1
\end{cases}$$
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \:\mathrm{d}x=\left[ 0\right]_0^1=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: if $f$ is a bounded function and has a finite amount of discontinuities on a compact interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$,

Check out this answer,

[$f$ bounded on $[a,b]$ with one or finite discontinuities implies $f$ Riemann-integrable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286233/f-bounded-on-a-b-with-one-or-finite-discontinuities-implies-f-riemann-in)